# How to select the window of rows which sum to a minimum value in each group and plot in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

**I want** to divide a column in a df into groups and run something like rollsum() for each 36 sequential rows in a column (Online_h) inside each group and select those rows, where the sum is the minimum inside the group (compared to the sum of the rest again inside the group). It means that for each group I should get 36 rows summing as minimum compared to others.

**My dataframe** includes three columns of "Date", "Online_h" and "week". Column "week" is used to group the data by. Rows summing to minimum for each 36 sequential row should be calculated on the values in "Online_h".

The df looks like this:
[Tha dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mClC.png)

My current code looks like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(df$SumsofOnline <- rollapply(Online_h, width = 36, sum)) %>%
  select(min(SumsofOnline))
```

This code groups the data correctly based on labels in "week", but fails to get rows after rollapply. I think that the reason is because rollapply gives only numbers which is already the sum of the calculation, but I need to get 36 rows in Online_h with condition that the sum will be minimum in each group (group_by(week)).

After the values are received, I need **to plot** a barplot of facets for each group and highlight those Dates, where the 36 sequential values in Online_h sum to be the minimum compared to other sequential sums.
For the plot, I have been using this code, but it is unfinished because the selection is not done correctly.

```
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Online_h)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_grid(rows = vars(week) )
```

For highlighting I think of using, `gghighlight().`

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The pipe starts with `df` but then you refer to `df_Hourly_DriverActivity`. Which is right?

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the code you've tried and with the output of `dput(df_Hourly_DriverActivity)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df_Hourly_DriverActivity, 50))`.

Comment: It should be df everywhere, edited already. Thanks for noting.

Comment: In the pipe there's no need for the data.frame's name. Remove the `df$` part and see if it works.

Comment: Alright, I just edited and removed the df in the pipe, but still it doesn't work, gives me this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = ... <- NULL`.
x replacement has 61 rows, data has 840
i The error occurred in group 1: week = 46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the following solves the question's problem.

```
library(dplyr)

window <- 10  # test value
df %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(Sums = zoo::rollapplyr(Online_h, width = window, sum, fill = NA)) %>%
  filter(Sums == min(Sums, na.rm = TRUE))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
## Groups:   week [3]
#  Online_h  week  Sums
#     <int> <int> <int>
#1       13    50   162
#2        6    51   184
#3       12    52   158
```

---

### Test data

```
set.seed(2021)
week = rep(50:52, sample(150:152))
n <- length(week)
df <- data.frame(
  Online_h = sample(50, n, TRUE),
  week
)
```

---

### Edit: graph

With a more complete data set, here is a plot with the sequences in blue and the other bars in grey, faceted by `week`. I use an auxiliary function `f` to determine which rows are in the minimal sequence.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(x){
  for(i in rev(seq_along(x)[-1])){
    if(!is.na(x[i]))
      if(x[i] > 1) {
        x[i - 1L] <- x[i] - 1L
      }
  }
  x
}

window <- 10

df %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(Sums = zoo::rollapplyr(Online_h, width = window, sum, fill = NA)) %>%
  mutate(IsMin = Sums == min(Sums, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(cnt = ifelse(IsMin, window, 0L)) %>%
  mutate(IsMin = (f(cnt) > 0 | IsMin) & !is.na(IsMin)) %>% 
  select(-cnt) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Sums, fill = IsMin)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "blue")) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
  labs(fill = "Minimum") +
  facet_wrap(~ week, scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))
```

[image]

---

### Data for 2nd example

```
set.seed(2021)
Date <- paste(Sys.Date() - 4*7, "23:00:00")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date)
Date <- seq(Date, length.out = 4*7*24, by = "1 hour")
week <- as.integer(format(Date, "%V"))
df <- data.frame(Date,
                 Online_h = sample(50, length(week), TRUE),
                 week)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
This code works exactly to find the minimum Sums and stores the Sums as a new column in the df. However, I need this to plot and highlight the 36 sequential values in Online_h for which the sum is minimum. Now I have the sums stored but can't relate their initial values in order to use them in the plot. Could you please help me to do that, too?

Comment: @Vahram Yes but I need data, like I said in a comment to the question. The test data in my answer doesn't have a date column.

Comment: Here is the data dput:
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1482087600, 1482084000, 1482080400, 
1482076800, 1482073200, 1482069600, 1482066000, 1482062400, 1482058800, 
1482055200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Online_h = c(18L, 
20L, 25L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 30L, 23L, 24L, 17L), week = c(51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")